# Using mpi4py how can I ask multiple nodes to run a python script in HPC cluster?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, mpi4py

I am actually trying to run a python script in HPC cluster. Previously, it took huge time to run and then to minimize the run time I have done parallel programming by using **`multiprocessing`** tools first. Everything was good, but the problem was I could use only one node and can ask highest 16 cores from the HPC to run my job. I have carefully read the functions of **`multiprocessing`** and found that it could not take more than one node to run a job and to recover this problem, I have done parallel programming again by using **`mpi4py`**. Everything is OK now and I can also use multiple cores in this case. But I found the same problem again that is, how can I ask multiple nodes from the HPC cluster to run the job, I know that I could do this by using MPI. Here I'm giving a code that could run with two cores and one node.

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
size = 2 * comm.Get_size()  #size of processors
rank = comm.Get_rank()  
N_conditions = 4             # no. of conditions

range_cond = range(rank / size * N_conditions, ((rank + 1) * 2/ size) * N_conditions)   # formula to generate range for all conditions

solution = [None] * len(range_cond) 

for i_conditions in range_cond:
    solution[i_conditions] = solve(i_conditions)  #solve is another function that could return all components of 'solution' for 'N_conditions'

total_solution = np.asarray(solution)
```

Comment: Unless you are running with a resource manager such as SLURM, you need to provide a machinefile that contains several hosts to `mpirun`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have already managed that job, the problem was in my PBS script.

Comment: @Photon I am also facing the same issue. It would be helpful if you can share your PBS script.